# Powershell should run a command for all the periods in a year

Tags: powershell

I have a command which I need to run on PowerShell, I can run it directly by providing a variable. Example:

```
command run 2017 Jan
```

But my requirement is to run the command within a loop for each of a list of variables:

```
Jan Feb Mar .... Oct Nov Dec

$ACSautoPath = "C:\sap\rexon\bin\rexon.bat"
$AutomationPath = "C:\Sap\Automation"
$LogPath = "C:\Sap\Automation\Log"
$BackupPath = "C:\Sap\Automation\Backup"
#Date Variables
$DaysToKeep = "-30"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($DaysToKeep)
$TimeStamp = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMddHHmm"
$LogFileName = "Backup" + $TimeStamp + ".log"
#ACS Variables
$ACSdomain = "yourdomain"
$ACSurl = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$ACSuser = "yourusername"
$ACSpass = "c:\ Sap\Automation\password.epw"
#Snapshot Variables
$ACSExportName = "Snapshot"
$ACSExportDownloadName = $ACSExportName + ".zip"
$ACSExportRename = $ACSExportName + $TimeStamp + ".zip"
#Start Logging
Start-Transcript -path $LogPath\$LogFileName
#Log into ACS
Write-Host ([System.String]::Format("Login to source: {0}", [System.DateTime]::Now))
&$ACSautoPath "login" $ACSuser $ACSpass $ACSurl
#Run A rule
Write-Host ([System.String]::Format("Run A rule: {0}",[System.DateTime]::Now))
&$ACSautoPath Runrule cons india 2017 jan 
#Log out of ACS
Write-Host ([System.String]::Format("Logout of source: {0}",[System.DateTime]::Now))
&$ACSautoPath "logout"
#Stop Logging
Stop-Transcript
```

At line:27 user has to provide a variable like Mar then line 27 has to be executed for all the periods in the list like explained below,

I should provide any period in the middle like `Mar` then loop has to run the command for:

```
apr may jun july aug sep oct nov dec jan feb
```

How this can be achieved?

Comment: Your question is quite vague and contains no actual code so we don't know what, or how, you are trying to do. (Always include your code even if it doesn't work!). I would recommend reading [ask] and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). These will help you figure out what your question is missing so you can update your question and get an answer that will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `$ACSautoPath` is the path to a batch file you pass arguments to,
but where stems the initial value `2017 jan` from?

I'll assume you want to start in current month and iterate the next eleven:

```
$Start = Get-Date     # or set a fixed date with # -year 2017 -month 1
0..11|ForEach-Object {
    $Params = "Runrule cons india {0}" -f $Start.AddMonths($_).ToString('yyyy MMM')
    &$ACSautoPath $Params
}
```

With `$ACSautoPath` temporarily set to `Echo` I get this output:

```
Runrule cons india 2018 Nov
Runrule cons india 2018 Dez
Runrule cons india 2019 Jan
Runrule cons india 2019 Feb
Runrule cons india 2019 Mrz
Runrule cons india 2019 Apr
Runrule cons india 2019 Mai
Runrule cons india 2019 Jun
Runrule cons india 2019 Jul
Runrule cons india 2019 Aug
Runrule cons india 2019 Sep
Runrule cons india 2019 Okt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the months from any starting point using the [modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-6):

```
$months = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames

$start = $months.IndexOf('Jul')

1 .. 12 | ForEach-Object { $months[++$start % 12] }
```

Which gives output like this:

```
Aug
Sep
Oct
Nov
Dec
Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
May
Jun
Jul
```

**EDIT:** Updated to include feedback from the rather more observant @LotPings

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames` ? And also ++$start ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it should be the abbreviations as that was in the question, but the position of the ++ means we use the position of the first month (July), then increment to the next one.  If it was before the variable, we’d increment first, then use that index (August) first.

Comment: cite: `like Mar then loop has to run the command for apr may...`

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  Should have probably not answered this just as I was rushing to lunch.   I’ll correct my answer when I’m back in the office.

Comment: Exactly What @lotpings says is my requirement.

Comment: In your Code, if the user starts from Jul, output starts from Aug,
Can we make output to start from Jul it self?

Comment: That's what I had originally, but it's not what you ask for - see LotPings comment above.  To get it to start from the month you specify (July in my example), change `++$start` to `$start++`.

Comment: Thankyou @BOXDOG
Your Suggestion helped.

Comment: One last question Where should my command should be in this,

$months = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames
$start = $months.IndexOf('Jul')
1 .. 12 | ForEach-Object { $months[++$start % 12] }


&$ACSautoPath Runrule cons india 2017 jan